# What is the explanation of these phenomena?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, everyday-life, biology

A person can jump high raising his 60 kg weight while he barely moves a rock of 60 kg.
A person can run fast with his massive 60 kg weight while he barely moves the same rock of 60 kg.
An average  person can lift his body of 60 kg holding a bar many times but he will barely move a rock of 60 kg.
It seems that a human when moves itself is lighter than the human body actual mass.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The body has evolved to be self supporting and mobile and not to carry rocks of equal weight. Had there been evolutionary pressure to carry 60kg rocks we may have taken the form of a wheel barrow.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue in your experimental comparisons.

When you jump you are lifting your 60 kg of bodymass with your massive thigh muscles. You can't conduct an experiment where you lift 60 kg of rock in the exact same way.

- If you stretch out your arms to lift it then you are using other muscle groups than the thighs, so not comparable.
- If you hold the rock over your head in order to lift it with your thighs then you are lifting *both* the rock *and* your body, so much more than just the 60 kg rock. Not comparable to the only-body-mass scenario.

What you could do is to compare the same muscle group in a manner that can be fairly isolated. For instance,

- Try holding the 60 kg of rock above your head and then do air push-ups on it - meaning bend and stretch your arms, bringing the rock up and down.
- Then afterwards do a handstand, possibly by having someone supporting your balancing horizontally without any vertical aid. You are now carrying 60 kg of bodymass with your arms in a fairly comparative manner. Do push-ups now. You might feel it as just as hard.

This is far from an accurate comparison, since the manner in which your muscle groups are used may still vary. But we are closer to a comparable experiment and you will most likely see a comparable result.

Comment: The rock of 60 kg in this case can not even be lift with arms by a bodybuilder but in the second case an average human can do it with little effort.

Comment: @YahyaSharif Indeed. Because other muscle groups are used.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a question of biology actually. The leg and hip muscles i.e. quads, glutes, hamstrings, hip flexors, calves used for running and jumping are stronger than arm muscles such as biceps which you would use to lift something. How you grip the object also plays a significant role, its much harder to grab a large and heavy object compared to lifting your own weight gripping a bar. Not having a great grip means that more muscles have to be used to compensate for it. Also remember that when you are carrying something your bodyweight and the weights are adding up.

Answer (score 1):

Because we evolved to do so. Jumping, running, and climbing are critical skills for homo sapiens survival. Pushing, not so much. Ask the same question to a rhino, and its answer will be the opposite.
If you somehow put human legs on a 60 kg rock and tell it to jump, it will jump just fine.
(also, pushing is harder because of friction)

Answer (score 1):

Centre of mass in case of lifting a 60 kg rock is concentrated in the rock. It will bend the whole body to move it. The centre of mass in case of self lifting is moved by muscles, and self supported by flesh and bones. Mass is also distributed to support your movement; like a race car design. This also has to do with stiffness. A hollow pipe with a similar length, will have the same stiffness with a non-hollow pipe. They will bear to lift the same mass before breaking.